# Laravel CI/CD in Gitlab, Docker set my IP MySQL

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I followed this [Gitlab tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/) to test and deploy Laravel applications with GitLab CI/CD and Envoy.

All works well, but when I run a pipeline it shows this error:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'172.17.0.4' (using password: YES)")

My IP server is **172.0.0.1** but the pipeline set the IP by **172.17.0.4**.

How can I set the IP to make work it?

Comment: Show me your connect DB in .env file....

Comment: The .env file has the correct password and variables. 

`
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=mypass`

Comment: Your mysql is running inside a docker container right ? If in that case, i think that connect `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 ` this way is problem...

Comment: Please show your `gitlab-ci.yml` file

Comment: `gitlab-ci.yml`:
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: blog
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: V4ld1v1@Ch1l3-2018
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_USERNAME: laravel
The file is: https://gitlab.com/albertcito/blog/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Try to edit your connect db in env like this : `DB_HOST=mysql`. make sure you run `php artisan config:cache`  to clear connect cache

Comment: Your `Mysql` run inside a container. So, connect via `localhost ip` is not the right way... You can run mysql image and inspect to check the connect ip, is not  `127.0.0.1`

Comment: It does not work. I think I have to add the `volume /var/lib/mysql/` then the image can copy my DB inside to the container.  I did it with `artifacts: paths: - /var/lib/mysql/` but it shows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it works. I added only this values to the `yml` file:

```
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
```

Obviously the same values to the `.env` file.

(I also uninstalled and re-installed MySQL, but I don't know if that helped to solve it)